# SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pg-hba.conf

i'm working on a project where i have to put a website on a server and i'm encountering this error :

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

So i already checked online, i did :
ufw allow 5432/tcp
(to allow port 5432 to be listen)

In the postgresql.conf, i changed listen_adresses='localhost' to listen_addresses='*'
In the pg_hba.conf, i put host    all             all             0.0.0.0                 md5

And i still got the error, if anyone can help me it would be great !

If it helps, the error appeared after i updated my postgres, and after i uncommented pdo_pgsql. I then restarted my database, then the error occured.

Comment: Did you restart the database after doing those things?

Comment: Hi, yes i did restart my database